# Android facebook how to go to website on clicking the post

Tags: android, facebook

In my android application I want to Post something on users Facebook wall and on clicking on the post the user has to redirected to the website.but now it is redirected to my app.How can I fix this.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

The code used for sharing on wall is

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                postParams.putString("name", "");
                postParams
                        .putString(
                                "caption",
                                "");
                postParams.putString("link", "http://www.something.com/");
                Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {

                        } else {
                            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                    .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                            String postId = null;
                            try {
                                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                                Log.i("TAG", "postId " + postId);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.i("TAG", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                };

                Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                        HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, Facebook doesn't allow posting of external url's apart from your facebook app page. However you can post image using external image url.
e.g.

```
postParams.putString("picture", "http://some/image_url");
```